# What skills are involved in exhorting and convincing the gainsayers?

Tags: paul, inspiration, teaching, faithful, faith

In Titus 1:9 we read "Holding fast the faithful word as he hath been taught, that he may be able by sound doctrine both to exhort and to convince the gainsayers."

I'd like to learn from both your doctrinal knowledge and practical expertise.

Comment: Are you asking if Titus 1:14 - "Not giving heed to Jewish fables" was a [skill] used to achieve Titus 1:9? | Please clarify your question.

Comment: Simply said: What was Titus being asked to do in Titus 1:9? It is up to your discretion what evidence and lessons to share in answering this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like something that belongs in Christianity Stack Exchange, since it is asking a question about doctrine and practice and not necessarily about Biblical texts.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the the same verse of Titus 1:9:

- (NIV) He must hold firmly to the trustworthy message as it has been taught, **so that he can** encourage others by sound doctrine and refute those who oppose it.
- (ESV) He must hold firm to the trustworthy word as taught, **so that he may** be able to give instruction in sound doctrine and also to rebuke those who contradict it.
- (BSB) He must hold firmly to the faithful word as it was taught, **so that he can** encourage others by sound teaching and refute those who contradict it.
- (NKJV) holding fast the faithful word as he has been taught, **that he may be able**, by sound doctrine, both to exhort and convict those who contradict.
- (NASB) holding firmly the faithful word which is in accordance with the teaching, **so that he will be able** both to exhort in sound doctrine and to refute those who contradict it.

Thus, the God-given skill, imparted by the Holy Spirit (John 16:13, 14, Matt 10:19) is to thoroughly understand the "*trustworthy message as it has been taught*" - to have a grasp of the Gospel of Jesus is a very precious gift that must be shared with all (Matt 28:19).

Thus to summarize Paul's statement in Titus 1:9 -

- The Skill: Hold firmly to the trustworthy word as taught
- The Purpose: to encourage other by sound doctrine and rebuke those who contradict.

Put another way, the gift of Holy Spirit (Acts 2:38) which was to guide them into all truth (John 16:13, 14) the believers continued steadfastly in the doctrine -(Acts 2:42). Emerging leaders studied to have a grasp of the Gospel and show themselves approved unto God as workmen of the Word (2 Timothy 2:15). It was called the apostles doctrine because (they had so studied it) they had made it their own, and genuinely held firmly to it as the faithful word.

This is consistent with Peter's instruction in 1 Peter 3:15 - "*But in your hearts sanctify Christ as Lord. Always be prepared to give a defense to everyone who asks you the reason for the hope that is in you. But respond with gentleness and respect*"

Comment: Up-voted +1 for the added perspective of I Peter 3:15 and its harmony with Titus 1:9